# Get video Id from XML youtube video using PHP

Tags: php, xml, video, youtube

I'm using PHP to process XML information. How can I get from the XML youtube the video id?

Question I have:

```
> $vid['title'] = $video->title;  $vid['date'] = $video->updated;
```

that works. Only I also want to be getting the video id

```
$vid['id'] = ?
```

I use this XML as example , off course I use the real feed.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<feed xmlns:yt="http://www.youtube.com/xml/schemas/2015" xmlns:media="http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
 <link rel="self" href="http://www.youtube.com/feeds/videos.xml?channel_id=UCCXoCcu9Rp7NPbTzIvogpZg&amp;orderby=published"/>
 <id>yt:channel:UCCXoCcu9Rp7NPbTzIvogpZg</id>
 <yt:channelId>UCCXoCcu9Rp7NPbTzIvogpZg</yt:channelId>
 <title>Fox Business</title>
 <link rel="alternate" href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCCXoCcu9Rp7NPbTzIvogpZg"/>
 <author>
  <name>Fox Business</name>
  <uri>https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCCXoCcu9Rp7NPbTzIvogpZg</uri>
 </author>
 <published>2008-02-04T12:35:54+00:00</published>
 <entry>
  <id>yt:video:yt9cwC3bySI</id>
  <yt:videoId>yt9cwC3bySI</yt:videoId>
```

Comment: I think you're using PHP to do this, but I'm not familiar with that language. Please specify the language you're using as an additional tag and mention it explicitly in your post.

Comment: yes thanks for comment. its is in php <?php
 
  $xml feed url  $return = array();
 
  foreach ($xml->entry as $video) {
      $vid = array();
 
      $vid['id'] =  $video->data->videoId;
      $vid['title'] = $video->title;
      $vid['date'] = $video->updated;
   $vid['views'] = $video->community->views;   onlye the video>data>videoId does not work,what do I wrong

Comment: ok thanks what do you mean? Changed caps and bold in accordance with normal SO formatting?

Answer (score 0):

**(1)** For `<yt:videoId>` You can try:

```
$vid['id'] = $video->{'yt:videoId'}
```

**(2)** For `<id>` You can try:

```
$vid['title'] = $video->id;
```

Or else finally try...  
Read not as XML but as a string of text. Use the PHP [String](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.strings.php) functions to extract the text that exists between the `<yt:videoId>` and `</yt:videoId>`.